Force GLM through zero
I am working on a glm model using a binomial distribution. I want to force the intercept through zero, as I know that biologically this makes sense. I have used the formula to y ~ 0 + x to try and achieve this, however, when I do this, the y intercept is exactly 0.5. I think this is due to the binomial function and the fact that I am predicting using 'response'. I think I need to incorporate the link function when I predict, but am not sure how to do this.
# simulate exponential relationship
set.seed(123)
# generate random x values between 0 and 60
x <- runif(400, 0, 60)
y <- 1 - exp(-0.075 * x) * rnorm(400, 0.7, 0.1)

data = data.frame(sr= x, fipar = y)
# Fit the GLM model with a custom link function
model <- glm(fipar ~ 0 + sr, 
             data = data, 
             family = binomial(link='logit'))

# Create an observed and predicted dataframe
data$predicted <- predict(model, data, type = "response",se.fit = T)$fit
data$se <- predict(model, data, type = "response",se.fit = T)$se.fit

# Plot the data and the model's predicted probabilities
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = sr, y = fipar)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21,fill='orange') +
  ylim(0,1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted), color = "green")+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = predicted - se, ymax = predicted + se), alpha = 0.2)




So.... the logistic curve fit by a binomial distribution asymptotically approaches 0 on the left and 1 on the right, but it never actually reaches those values. You could force the curve arbitrarily far to the right to get the value at 0 to be as close to 0 as possible, but since it's symmetric around the inflection point that will mess up your fit.

You talk about fitting a GLM using the binomial distribution, but the response in your example (y) is not binomially distributed. What does your actual data set look like?
